# How to have a scatter plot with mutiple axes in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

In R, the iris table contains the following attributes:

- Sepal.Length
- Sepal.Width
- Petal.Length
- Petal.Width
- Species

I have learned that it's possible to use the following package to view a scatter plot of 2 values only in the dataset which are Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width in this case:

```
library(ggvis)
iris %>% ggvis(~Sepal.Length, ~Sepal.Width, fill = ~Species) %>%
layer_points()
```

My question is as follows:
I need to have the scatter plot but for the the first 4 attributes in the dataset to represent the species. How can this be done?

If not in R, is there any other tool that can do this?

Comment: Make a scatterplot matrix, googling for `r scatterplot matrix` or `r ggplot2 scatterplot matrix` should get you started.

Comment: Thank you.. will check it for sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in functin `pairs`. If you want to add colors to it as in your example, you can add parameter `col`. Here you have the code:

```
pairs(iris[,1:4], col = iris$Species, pch=16) # parameter pch=16 changes the points to be filled dots.
```

**Output:**

[image]